# Windows reports internet connection fine but can't load any pages

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

Since yesterday, I am unable to load any web-pages in any browser, I just get time-outs.

- I am able to ping e.g. www.google.com from the command line and this works fine
- I am able to establish a VPN connection to a remote network and RDP in - this is how I'm accessing SE to post this - but it is incredibly slow
- Even when I connect to the VPN, I *still* cannot load any pages on my local machine even though this normally works just fine
- All my other devices (phone, iPad) work just perfectly with no sign of slow connection or anything wrong at all

So it's like my PC has just decided I cannot use the internet. It seems notable to me that loading pages either through my normal internet connection *and* through the VPN both fail?

I have already:

- Rebooted the PC
- Turned the WiFi off and on
- Forgotten the WiFi network and re-joined
- disabled real-time protection through Defender

I haven't manually changed anything since yesterday and I am unable to do any work which is costing me a considerable amount, and I have no idea what I can do.

Comment: Try Resetting your firewall to Default. This issue has been happening to windows 10 a lot lately with internet issues. Also try doing cmd.exe and running `sfc /scannow` check your browsers to see if there are any odd vpns. One other thing to look at is your host file to see if something has been changed.

Comment: Does a wired connection work?

Comment: @DavidPostill this is a wire-less only setup so I cannot test that - that _is_ the other obvious first thing to try so good to point out

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers? Do you have other devices/pc's in your network and can they browse the web fine?

Comment: As per my question: it affects all browsers on the PC in question, and other devices work just fine.

Comment: Have you scanned this computer for viruses and malware (two different things)? If not, do so to make sure the computer is clean before continuing to troubleshoot. I have seen many people waste hours on connection issues only to find they have a virus or malware.